# Robot Framework How to Get Text Item

Tags: python, json, string, robotframework

I wrote the code to extract data from a dictionary and want to keep the information in the format as below.

```
A = 2018
B = 8
A = 2019
B = 2
A = 2020
B = 3
```

Row data, I want to access the data points from below.

```
[
  {
    "A": 2018,
    "B": 8,
    "C": 7,
    "D": 8,
    "E": 0.0,
    "F": 8,
    "G": 8,
    "H": 8,
  },
  {
    "A": 2019,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 5,
    "D": 6,
    "E": 0,
    "F": 9,
    "G": 16,
    "H": 5,
  },
  {
    "A": 2020,
    "B": 3,
    "C": 8,
    "D": 61,
    "E": 0,
    "F": 2,
    "G": 1,
    "H": 2,
  },
]
```

Please help me find a solution. Thanks

Comment: `Row data, I want to access the data points from below.` I have no idea how to associate a meaning with this - even substituting *raw* for `Row`. For `E`, is there a difference in meaning between `0.0` and `0`? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = [
  {
    "A": 2018,
    "B": 8,
    "C": 7,
    "D": 8,
    "E": 0.0,
    "F": 8,
    "G": 8,
    "H": 8,
  },
  {
    "A": 2019,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 5,
    "D": 6,
    "E": 0,
    "F": 9,
    "G": 16,
    "H": 5,
  },
  {
    "A": 2020,
    "B": 3,
    "C": 8,
    "D": 61,
    "E": 0,
    "F": 2,
    "G": 1,
    "H": 2,
  },
]

b = ""

for item in a:
    b = b + "A:" + str(item["A"]) + "\n" + "B:" + str(item["B"]) + "\n"
    
print(b)

Output: 
A:2018
B:8
A:2019
B:2
A:2020
B:3
```